# The Mix manifest does not exist when using orchestral/testbench

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Creating a custom Laravel package using the [orchestral/testbench](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench) package that helps package developer to help with PHPUnit test. So, my package on a different place and not in a Laravel installation exactly. Everything works great except the `mix()` function that I'm using on the blade view for resources.

```js
<script src="{{ asset(mix('js/app.js', 'vendor/trade')) }}"></script>
```

And, I have the following test route set in the `web.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('trade::_layouts.app');
});
```

In addition, I have the following feature test in the `ExampleTest.php` file:

```
public function testBasicTest()
{
    $response = $this->get('/');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

When I am running `phpunit` I am seeing the following error:

```
Expected status code 200 but received 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

After dumping the `$response` in the test, I see the `The Mix manifest does not exist.` error. After digging for an hour I found that `mix()` helper function is looking for the `mix-manifest.json` in the `orchestral/testbench` package located under the `vendor` instead of the `public` folder in my package.

I tried to the following in the package `ServiceProvider.php` but didn't work either:

```
$this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return base_path().'/../public';
});
```

In addition, I see the `laravel/horizon` package also using the `mix()` helper function on the `layout.blade.php` file as I am doing right now and it is also using the `orchestral/testbench` package for the test. So, how horizon package is doing the test while I can't? What is the to override `mix()` helper to ensure the public path is on my package `public` path instead of the `orchestral/testbench` path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to override the `public_path()` returned path to ensure the `mix()` function can find the `mix-manifest.json` file.

1. One would be to override the `public_path()` method completely to the custom package. Laravel usage `if (!function_exists()) {}` before declaring any function which is good as we can define our own `public_path()` function in our package. However, we'll need to make sure that our override function loads before the Laravel helper method and that's another topic.
2. The easiest way would be to change the `path.public` from Laravel IoC Container from the particular PHPUnit test where we're having the issue.

```php
public function testBasicTest()
{
    $this->app->instance('path.public', $packagePublicDir);

    $response = $this->get('/');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to run `npm install && npm run dev`